# Is there a way to see if a GPIO pin is on or off using the python RPi.GPIO module?

Tags: python, rpi.gpio

I have a relay connected to the RPi. Pin 12 for output on/off and grounded with pin 6. Currently I have two python scripts one for turning pin 12 on and another to turn it off. My goal is to run a single script to toggle pin pin 12 on and off.

Right now I have two scripts to do this.

on.py

```
import RPi.GPIO as io

io.setmode(io.BOARD)
io.setup(12,io.OUT)
io.output(12,1)
```

off.py

```
import RPi.GPIO as io

io.setmode(io.BOARD)
io.setup(12,io.OUT)
io.output(12,0)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! What do you mean be "in use"? That it was not used before by this script or by any other program before? I doubt that there is something like that available. But then again what is the actual purpose of this call?

Comment: You can obviously get the state of the pins, but "in use" is abstract.  If some process set the state of something, who's to know if it intends to do it again in 3 seconds?  Etc.  As far as I'm aware there's no enforceable locking mechanism for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To toggle the relay, regardless of it being on or off:

```
import RPi.GPIO as io

io.setmode(io.BOARD)
io.setup(12,io.OUT)

io.output(12, not io.input(12))
```

The io.input() function will return a 1 if the pin is on and a 0 if it is off.

*Source: Getting Started with Raspberry Pi by Matt Richardson & Shawn Wallace pg.138*

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to determine if something is connected to the pin really with what you are wanting. Your best bet would be to get the mode of the pin, and determine if it is the mode you want.

The only real way to determine if something is connected to the pins, is only if it is using a bus like I2C or SPI.

Here is how you can check the mode of a pin.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
func = GPIO.gpio_function(pin)
```

will return a value from:
GPIO.IN, GPIO.OUT, GPIO.SPI, GPIO.I2C, GPIO.HARD_PWM, GPIO.SERIAL, GPIO.UNKNOWN

Comment: I wanted to see the state of the pin, either on or off. You answered my question but not what I ment, sorry.